# How to use qscc in node js sdk?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to use GetTransactionByID from qscc.
Using the code from one of the examples, I tried running this :-

```
import fs from 'fs';
import yaml from 'js-yaml';
import path from 'path';
import { Wallets, Gateway } from 'fabric-network';

export async function submitTransaction(txnName: string, args: Array<any>) {
    const walletPath = path.join(
        process.cwd(),
        '../identity/user/isabella/wallet',
    );
    const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);

    const gateway = new Gateway();

    try {
        const userName = 'isabella';
        const yamlFile = path.join(
            process.cwd(),
            '../gateway/connection-org2.yaml',
        );
        let connectionProfile: any = yaml.load(
            fs.readFileSync(yamlFile, 'utf8'),
        );
        let connectionOptions = {
            identity: userName,
            wallet: wallet,
            discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true },
        };

        console.log('Connect to Fabric gateway.');

        await gateway.connect(connectionProfile, connectionOptions);

        console.log('Use network channel: mychannel.');

        const network = await gateway.getNetwork('mychannel');

        const contract = await network.getContract('qscc');

        console.log('Submitting transaction');

        const response = await contract.submitTransaction(txnName, ...args);

        console.log('Transaction Response :-');

        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(`Error processing transaction. ${error}`);
        console.log(error.stack);
    } finally {
        console.log('Disconnection from gateway');
        gateway.disconnect();
    }
}

submitTransaction('GetTransactionByID', [
    'mychannel',
    'f02954ae3723721459596f3ccdd89b36f8eca11d851f1aa7aeb4cb0bab148ab9',
]);
```

But I get the following error:-

2021-02-11T17:25:46.564Z - warn: [TransactionEventHandler]: strategyFail: commit failure for transaction "476873023684d8af68f5e05c965fee91be06255659eabd961601dad05501de03": TransactionError: Commit of transaction 476873023684d8af68f5e05c965fee91be06255659eabd961601dad05501de03 failed on peer peer0.org2.example.com:9051 with status INVALID_CHAINCODE

I can invoke the same using peer cli :-

peer chaincode invoke -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA" -C mychannel -n qscc -c '{"function":"GetTransactionByID","Args":["mychannel", "f02954ae3723721459596f3ccdd89b36f8eca11d851f1aa7aeb4cb0bab148ab9"]}'

How can I invode this chaincode in node js application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to query the ledger, you may want to use `contract.evaluateTransaction` instead of `contract.submitTransaction`.

From [Fabric Node SDK doc for Fabric NetworkContract interface](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/module-fabric-network.Contract.html):

The Contract allows applications to:

- Submit transactions that store state to the ledger using submitTransaction.
- Evaluate transactions that query state from the ledger using evaluateTransaction.